# Java String.split() spiralling out of control

Tags: java, regex, split

I am trying to parse strings (some can be very long, paragraphs) based on white space (spaces, return keys, tabs). Currently using `String.split("\\s++")`. In the previous project we are updating, we had simply used `StringTokenizer`. Using `String.split("\\s++")` works just fine in all our testing and with all our beta testers.

The minute we release it to expanded users, it runs for a while until it soaks up all server resources. From what I've researched, it appears to be catastrophic backtracking. We get errors like:

```java
    ....was in progress with java.base@11.0.5/java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4804)
    java.base@11.0.5/java.util.regex.Pattern$Start.match(Pattern.java:3619)
    java.base@11.0.5/java.util.regex.Matcher.search(Matcher.java:1729)
    java.base@11.0.5/java.util.regex.Matcher.find(Matcher.java:746)
    java.base@11.0.5/java.util.regex.Pattern.split(Pattern.java:1264)
    java.base@11.0.5/java.lang.String.split(String.java:2317)
```

Users can type some crazy text. What is the best option to parse strings that could be anywhere from 10 characters to 1000 characters long? I am at a brick wall. Been trying different patterns (regex is not my strongest area) for the past 4 days without long term success.

Comment: Can you please include steps to reproduce? I tried `str.split("\\s++")` where `str` was a 16,000 character string but it finished basically instantly.

Comment: Why are you using `\\s++`? It should be failing to meet your criteria from my understanding. I am 99% certain that you actually need `\s+` based on my limited knowledge of Java string interpolation/escaping.

Comment: `++` is the possessive version of the greedy `+` quantifier

Comment: `\s++` cannot cause any backtracking, so the issue is not CB.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution if you dont trust the regex is to use a non regex based solution such as ApacheCommons StringUtils#split.  Alternatively, its pretty easy to write one yourself.

Keep in mind the difference between using StringTokenizer versus a split function is the tokenizer is lazy. If you were only retrieving a subset of the split results you may be eating up more memory with a split.  I would only expect this to be a problem with large strings though.